# Shiny: Source file to refresh data with observe

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `helper.R`, which I want to source from `app.R` to refresh data. `helper.R` has path variables based on `Sys.Date()`, like

```
data_path <- paste0("data_", Sys.Date(), ".csv")
```

I have a shiny application running on a shiny server and I want to source `helper.R` everyday using `observe`

**helper.R**

```
cur_date <- Sys.Date()
```

**app.R**

```
observe({
    invalidateLater(10000, session)
    if (Sys.Date() > cur_date) {
        source("helper.R")
    }
})
```

For some reason this setup is not working for data refresh. I am not much familiar with scope of variables in R. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add `invalidateLater()` into the observer statement https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/invalidateLater.html

Comment: sorry, I have it in the code, forgot to mention here.